# MySQL Multiple SUM statements in one query with case

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I have the following MySQL query, that counts the number of bookings for a certain day :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-01-31",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-02-05"
FROM bookingstable WHERE booking_location = 4
```

Now I would like to have this query to count the SUM of the booking prices for these days.

```
SELECT
    SUM(`booking_price` CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-01-31",
    SUM(`booking_price` CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-02-05"
FROM bookingstable WHERE booking_location = 4
```

One would say the above mentioned could be correct. Still it isn't. My fault for a 100%. But that's a sidenote since I am still learning MySQL.

I hope someone could point me out to my error.

Since the following is working :

```
SELECT SUM(booking_price) total_from_bookings
  FROM bookingstable 
 WHERE booking_location = 4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is what you are after:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN `booking_price` END) AS "2020-01-31",
    SUM(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN `booking_price` END) AS "2020-02-05"
FROM bookingstable 
WHERE booking_location = 4
```

Also if `booking_creationdate`'s data type is `datetime` don't treat it like a string (even if MysQL allows it).
If you want to extract the date part of the column use the function `DATE()`, like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(booking_creationdate) = '2020-01-31' THEN `booking_price` END) AS "2020-01-31",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(booking_creationdate) = '2020-02-05' THEN `booking_price` END) AS "2020-02-05"
FROM bookingstable 
WHERE booking_location = 4
```